# ¿Como hacer que una funcion se dispare despues de que se cargue todo el documento?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actualmente obtengo un conteo de filas a travez de una pequeña consulta y dicho resultado lo mando a mi pagina principal que esta creada en asp.net

Actualmente lo estoy haciendo de estas formas y ninguna me ha funcionado.

Forma 1

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function () {
          var lbltext = document.getElementById('lblPlanta').innerHTML;
          alert(lbltext);

      });

  </script>
```

Forma 2

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function () {
          var lbltext = document.getElementById('lblPlanta').textContent;
          alert(lbltext);

      });

  </script>
```

Forma 3

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function () {
          value = $("#lblPlanta").text();  
          alert(value);

      });

  </script>
```

Forma 4

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function () {
          value = $("#lblPlanta").val();  
          alert(value);

      });

  </script>
```

Forma 5

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function () {
          var lbltext = document.getElementById('lblPlanta').value;
          alert(lbltext);

      });

  </script>
```

Asi esta creada el Label. (En el codigo el label esta arriba del script)

```
<label id="lblPlanta"></label>
```

Inicialmente esta vacia la etiqueta porque ese se rellena de manera automatica, con el resultado que retorna de la BD. Dicho resultado lo imprimo en ese label y si se imprime pero el problema es que no lo puedo obtener para asignarlo a una variable.

Asignacion de la informacion a la etiqeuta

```
function getPlantas() {
    block();
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../../pagina/configuracion/empresa/confEmpresa.aspx/getPlanta",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#lblPlanta").html(data.d);

            $.unblockUI();
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $.unblockUI();
        }
    });
}
```

> **Actualizacion**

Al parecer mi problema es que intento obtener un valor antes de que este se cargue a travez del document.ready, asi que lo sustitui por el siguiente metodo:

```
  $(window).load(function () {
      value = $("#lblPlanta").text(); 
      alert(value);
  });
```

Pero me sigue trayendo en blanco el alert, alguien me podria mencionar alguna manera de hacer que se ejecute mi metodo despues de que todo se haya cargado.

Comment: en que momento asignas el valor al label y como lo asignas? puedes poner ese código?

Comment: listo, ya actualice la publicacion

Comment: la función getPlantas() en que momento se ejecuta?

Comment: creo que lo que pasa es que intentas obtener el valor antes de que hayas asignado el valor

Comment: se ejecuta al momento de que se lee el archivo de html, ya que se agrega a un metodo principal que va ejecutando todos los demas metodos que sean necesario al iniciarse la carga de la pagina.

Comment: en el codigo tengo la etiqueta arriba del script, tambien habia pensado eso

Comment: Estás asignando el valor a la variable cuando el `document` esté listo. Probablemente antes de que se ejecute `getPlantas()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las llamadas AJAX no son **deterministicas** en cuanto al tiempo que les puede tomar obtener el resultado a la petición. La mayoría de las veces esta sera retornada casi al instante, pero **no es posible de controlar** eso, la servidor que atiende a la petición puede estar congestionado y demorarse más de lo normal en responder y eso no lo puedes saber de antemano.

Por eso el camino no es subscribirse al **window.onload** o al **dom.ready**, ya que lo más probable de hecho es el código que realiza la llamada AJAX se comience a ejecutar justamente como respuesta a uno de estos dos eventos, y por lo tanto aún pasara un tiempo desde que se lanzaron los eventos anteriores y obtener la respuesta del servidor y colocar el resultado en el elemento **#lblPlanta**.

Una correcta solución ya la planteo **@Naos** y es subscribirte a un evento personalizado sobre el elemento **#lblPlanta** que lea su valor, y lanzar este evento desde el final del método **success** que realiza la petición AJAX.

```js
function onLblPlantaChange () {
    var lblPlantaValue = $('#lblPlanta').text();
    alert(lblPlantaValue);
}

// Me subscribo al evento change sobre el elemento
// y le asigno una función manejadora.
// En este caso que lea el valor desde el elemento
$('#lblPlanta').on('change', onLblPlantaChange);

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://httpbin.org/get?d=Orquidea',
    success: function (data) {
        // Fijo el valor en el evento
        // y lanzo el evento para que sea leido por
        // la función manejadora.
        $('#lblPlanta')
            .text(data.args.d)
            .trigger('change')
        ;

    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="lblPlanta">Valor Original</div>
```

Espero esto aclare un poco el problema.

Suerte y Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Basandome en tu pregunta y los comentarios que haz hecho y otros usuarios han comentado puedes estar a la *escucha* en tu *documento* cuando el *contenido* de `x elemento` sea cambiado, ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $(document).on('contentchanged', '#miElemento', function()   {
    // El contenido del elemento #miElemento a sido cambiado
    console.log($('#miElemento').html());
  })

  $('#btn').click(function(){
    if($('#miElemento').html() == 'Valor'){
      $('#miElemento').html('Prueba')
    }else{
      $('#miElemento').html('Valor')
    }
    
    $('#miElemento').trigger('contentchanged')
  })
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<label type="text" id="miElemento">Valor</label>
<button type="button" id="btn">Cambiar valor</button>
```

Entonces, para que en tu código funcione simplemente puedes agregar esto antes de tu función y una línea dentro de esta de la siguiente manera:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('contentchanged', '#lblPlanta', function()   {
        // El contenido del elemento #lblPlanta a sido cambiado
        console.log($('#lblPlanta').html());
    })

    function getPlantas() {
        block();
        $.ajax({
            url: "../../../pagina/configuracion/empresa/confEmpresa.aspx/getPlanta",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#lblPlanta").html(data.d);
                $("#lblPlanta").trigger('contentchanged'); // "Gatillamos"  el cambio al pedazo de código anterior
                $.unblockUI();
            }, 
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                $.unblockUI();
            }
        });
    }

    getPlantas();

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con la misma funcion con la que asignas:

```
var texto = $("#lblPlanta").html();
```

Pero no puedes usarlo en un

```
$(document).ready(...
```

ya que ese codigo se ejecuta al cargar la página y en ese momento tu aun no tienes el valor cargado. Tendras que obtenerlo en el momento en el que lo necesites.

Comment: bueno eso ya lo comprendi, pero entonces lo necesito al cargarse la pagina, y si lo hago en un onload, marca el mismo error, sabrias la forma de hacerlo automatico pero hasta la carga del documento completo.

Comment: ¿Pero tienes cargado el valor en el label en el momento en el que se carga la página?

Comment: si, porque lo imprimo, y lo puedo ver al cargar la pagina, si me retorna un valor

Answer (score 0):

Declara una variable global

```
var planta;
```

Asígnala en la función getPlantas

```
success: function (data) {
    $("#lblPlanta").html(data.d);
    planta =  data.d;      
    $.unblockUI();
},
```

Ya que hayas hecho eso puedes usar la variable planta y obtener su valor

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() { ... });
```

Está diseñado para hacer (entre otras cosas) es asegurarse de que su función se llama una vez que todos los elementos DOM de la página están listos para usarse.

Creo que esa sería.